# Is it possible to split production and development Bower components?

Tags: package-managers, bower

Is it possible to install development Bower components in a separate directory, so I could add it to `.gitignore`?

For example:

```
components
└─jquery
dev_components
└─bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could easily add the individual components to your `.gitignore`:

```
components/bootstrap
```

Comment: Can't I use `devDependencies` from `bower.json` somehow?

Comment: Bower will only use one folder. Having it juggle between multiple folder would have been fragile and over-complicated. Though you could just use the `production` flag `bower install --production` to not install devDependencies.

Comment: I am developing something for that. Will come back to you