# Brunch / Bower testing

Tags: bower, brunch

When looking at bower.json, I assume putting things in `devDependencies` is the recommended way to deal with things such unit testing dependencies. I'd like to use [qunit](http://qunitjs.com/) as my testing framework, but I guess it should apply to other frameworks as well.

The problem I have is that when I put qunit in devDependencies, it doesn't get picked up when building `vendor.js`. That's expected, but then how do I go with asking brunch to include it? Obviously, I'd prefer to have `test-vendor.js` where I'd have dependencies + devDependencies, while keeping devDependencies out of `vendor.js`.

I have this in `config.coffee`:

```
exports.config =
  # See http://brunch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html for documentation.
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
        'javascripts/vendor.js': /^(bower_components|vendor)/
        'test/javascripts/test.js': /^test\/(?!vendor)/
        'test/javascripts/test-vendor.js': /^test\/(?=vendor)/
```

Obviously, the last line wouldn't pick up any bower_component items as-is. Any suggestions here?

I saw this ticket:

- https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components/pull/7

but it looks it's still up in the air.

This SOq:

- [Is it possible to split production and development Bower components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211413/is-it-possible-to-split-production-and-development-bower-components)

suggests there's no way to do it from bower side at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Until this is implemented natively in Brunch, you can hack around it like this, so long as you aren't using Windows:

1. Add quint and other test dependencies to devDependencies in bower.json.  They will now be managed under bower_components.
2. Add a symlink for each test dependency from your test/ directory to the relevant file under bower_components, eg:

> `ln -s ../bower_components/qunit/qunit.js test/`

The dependencies will then be included in your unit-tests.js.

When brunch supports devDependencies, you can delete the symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

See [Ignore directories in brunch production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419415/ignore-directories-in-brunch-production-build?rq=1)

You should be able to do something like:

```
overrides:
  production:
    conventions:
      ignored: /[\/\\]_|bower_components[\/\\]qunit/
```

And then generate your production build with `brunch b -P` (`brunch build --production`)